# How to skip to a specific frame in a given spectrogram file

Tags: signal-processing, librosa

I'm encountering problems skipping ahead to a specific frame of a melspec feature set found [here](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.melspec). The aim of getting features from the feature set is to analyse the difference in beats per second (BPS) so that i can match up the BPS of two tracks in order to mix between the two tracks or warp the timing of the track to synchronise the two pieces of music together. The feature set does specify the [following](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/):

> ```
> Pre-extracted in the "feature" directory are space-delimited floating-point ASCII matrices: 
> beat_synchronus: one beat-synchronus vector per line 
> non-beat-synchronus: 512-sample hop frames @ 22050Hz sample rate, one vector per line one vector per line:"
> ```

I'm not quite sure how to interpret this - is the melspec beat or non beat synchronous and how does that work in regards to delimitating frames?

I've got as far as working out the frame duration thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008113/how-can-you-load-a-spectrogram-from-file-using-librosa) answer but I don't know how to apply the knowledge gained from the frame duration to the task of navigating to a specific timecode or frame. The closest I've got is working out the offset divided by the frame to work out how many frames need to be skipped to get to the offset (1 second into the track for example gives 2583 frames). However, the file is not demarcated into lines and as far as I can tell is just a continuous list of entries. This leads to the question of what the size is of a given frame is (if that's the right terminology) is it the case that it is 2383 entries to the second need to be skipped to get to the right entry or is it the case that each frame has a specific number of entries and I need to skip 2583 frames of size x? what is size x (512?)?

I've been able to open the file for melspec but for the melspec file there are no delimiters between entries. It is instead a continuous list of entries.

The code I have so far is as follows to work out the duration of a frame, and therefore the number of frames in an offset track to be skipped. However this does not indicate the size of a given frame and how to access that from the file for the melspec.
    `spectrogram` is the file_path for a given feature set. The `offset` is the time in seconds offset from the start of a track.

```
def skipToFrame(spectrogram, offset):
    SAMPLE_RATE =22050
    HOP_LENGTH = 512
    #work out the duration of each frame.
    FRAME_TIME = HOP_LENGTH/SAMPLE_RATE
    # work out how many frames are in the offset period (e.g 1 second).
    SHIFT_FRAMES = offset/FRAME_TIME

    # readlines of file so that offset is applied.
    with open(spectrogram) as feature_set:
        indices = int(SHIFT_FRAMES)
        for line in feature_set:
              print(line)
        feature_set.close()
```

This gives a list of 10 lines of results, which do not seem to be naturally delimited by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sample file](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.melspec) you are referring is a matrix of 128 x 7392 values. 
To better understand the format of this file, you may look at the [`extractFeatures.py`](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/extractFeatures.py) script used to extract the features. You may notice that the `melspec` feature is described as  "non-beat-synchronus" and computed using [`librosa.feature.melspectrogram`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html), using mostly default arguments and producing an output `S` of `n_mel` rows by `t` columns.

To figure out the value of `n_mel` you need to look at [`librosa.filters.mel`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.filters.mel.html), which indicates a default value of 128. The number of frames `t` on the other hand is computed internally in [`librosa.util.frame`](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/754fc3c51b96b9d0e5ce5cdec093798464c08612/librosa/util/utils.py#L102) as `1 + int((len(y) - frame_length) / hop_length)`, where the `frame_length` uses the default value 2048 and the `hop_length` uses the default value 512.

To summarize, the 128 rows correspond to the 128 MEL-frequency bins, and the 7392 columns correspond to time frames.
You could thus use the following to extract the column of interest:

```
def skipToFrame(spectrogram, offset):
    SAMPLE_RATE =22050
    HOP_LENGTH = 512
    #work out the duration of each frame.
    FRAME_TIME = HOP_LENGTH/SAMPLE_RATE
    # work out how many frames are in the offset period (e.g 1 second).
    SHIFT_FRAMES = offset/FRAME_TIME

    # readlines of file so that offset is applied.
    with open(spectrogram) as feature_set:
        indices = int(SHIFT_FRAMES)
        for line in feature_set:
          print(line.split(" ")[indices])
        feature_set.close()
```

Using `numpy` you could also read the entire spectrogram and address a specific column:

```
import numpy as np

def skipToFrame(spectrogram, offset):
    SAMPLE_RATE =22050
    HOP_LENGTH = 512
    #work out the duration of each frame.
    FRAME_TIME = HOP_LENGTH/SAMPLE_RATE
    # work out how many frames are in the offset period (e.g 1 second).
    SHIFT_FRAMES = offset/FRAME_TIME

    data = np.loadtxt(spectrogram)
    column = int(SHIFT_FRAMES)
    print(data[:,column])
```

Going back on the fact that the feature extraction was done using `librosa`, you may also consider using [`librosa.core.time_to_frames`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.time_to_frames.html) instead of manually computing the frame number:

```
def skipToFrame(spectrogram, offset):
    SHIFT_FRAMES = librosa.core.time_to_frames(offset, sr=22050, hop_length=512, n_fft=2048)
    ...
```

On a final note, you should be aware that each of these time frame uses 2048 samples, but they overlap such that each successive frame advances 512 sample relative to the previous sample. So the frames cover the following time intervals:

```
frame #  | start (s) |  end (s)
================================
1        |   0.000   |   0.093
2        |   0.023   |   0.116
3        |   0.046   |   0.139
...
41       |   0.929   |   1.022
42       |   0.952   |   1.045
...
7392     | 171.619   | 171.712
```

Comment: if the 7392 respond to time frames how many frames does a second make up i.e. how many column entries are in a given frame?

Comment: Each column is a time frame. There probably are between 3784704 and 3786240 samples at 22050Hz in the original input file (with up to 1536 samples of padding), so that's ~171.7 seconds. For 1 second, you'd have about 41 frames.